# Android Intent to launch yahoo messenger

Tags: android

I would like when a user taps a button to launch an application which understands the yahoo messenger link ymsgr:sendim?testlink

In this case if the Yahoo messenger application is installed on the device ,this app would be launched as opposed to the browser app

I have tried this with the following code but it does not work

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ymsgr:sendim?test@yahoo.com"));
         startActivity(i);
```

If the link is an http link to a website this would launch the browser. I would like to launch the Yahoo messenger app on the device if installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch an application with the package name:

```
public void openApplication(String packageName) {
  Intent iLaunch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
  startActivity(iLaunch);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can get from your question is:

You will have to create a Yahoo messenger client in Android. You can use the Openymsg API to implement that.

```
    Session session=new Session();
    session.login("Email Id", "password");
```

You can then do the above.